# Microsoft Teams: Share only part of a desktop

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams, presentations

Presenting with Microsoft Teams: I don't like to share the whole desktop, because there are some issues (when my desktop is pretty big, people with smaller displays can't read well, chat popups come out and the content is visible to everyone, I want to keep some notes aside, but I don't want them to be visible to others, general privacy issues).
Sharing a single application or window is not an option, because I need to show multiple windows from different programs.

If I could open a "transparent" window that shows everything "underneath", I could only share that one.
Moving and resizing this "transparent" window would be like using a "virtual camera" on the desktop to offer different views and resolutions to my participants.

Comment: How are you sharing? With what?

Comment: Depending on the type of applications you want to share, you could consider using a remote desktop connection to another machine on which you run the applications (and share only the RDP window). Or use a virtual machine running on your own system.

Comment: Using RDP o VM is not applicable.